# Powershell Copy-item command not working in script although it does work when run from a command line

Tags: powershell

I am on a Windows 7 machine trying to execute a PowerShell script to copy a template directory to another directory.  The command I am executing looks like: 
`Copy-Item -path "$projectsFolder$SourceFolder" -destination "$Test" -recurse -verbose;`

The parameters are as follows:

`path: C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TemplateSolution\Source


Destination: C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\source\main`

When I run this command at a PowerShell prompt, the files are copied correctly.  If I try and execute the command in the script with verbose enabled, it appears to copy the files and directories, but only the top level directory is created in the file system.  I am not sure why this would happen and I would appreciate any guidance or troubleshooting steps to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put quotes around the directory names if they have spaces in them. Also, you may need the -Force parameter to create destination directories if they do not exist.

Comment: I have implemented the change above and done some more testing.  It appears the root issue is that when the path contains "Source", it is never created by the script.  I have done some digging and I can not find anywhere that "Source" would be reserved.  The workaround for now is to use "Src" instead of "Source".  Thanks for the help.